# Open Powerpoint from Node in presentation Mode with presenter view

Tags: node.js, powerpoint

I have to open a Powerpoint directly in presentation mode from my software. So far no problem.

```
 let child = cp.exec( 'path/to/powerpoint.exe' + ' "' + 'path/to/presentation.pptx' + ' /s' '"', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
        console.error('stderr', stderr);
                    throw error;
    } else {
        console.log('done', stdout, stderr);
    }
```

So far no big thing. But if there are two Monitors on the computer Powerpoint will not switch to presenter mode, as the parameter /s seems to force single monitor view. If I open Powerpoint normal and then start the presentation manually it recognizes the second monitor ans starts in presenter view.

Does anybody know a trick to start a pptx in presentation mode in presenter view via Node?